# Transfer all keys of a HashMap into ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

I am getting all the keys in a map into a HashSet.

I want to be able to transfer this into an ArrayList.

Answer (score 5):

Did you mean this :

```
Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
List<K> list = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are already aware that `Set<KeyType> set = map.keySet()` returns a Set of the keys:

to put these into an `ArrayList<KeyType>` you can simply do `new ArrayList(set);`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the addAll method?

```
Set<KeyType> keys = map.keySet();
List<KeyType> res = new ArrayList<>();
res.addAll(keys);
```

No?

Comment: "No?" No! Never suggest to use raw types.

Comment: well this is just an exemple without types declared as the OP didn't provide is code... but nevermind i'm used to see comment of this sort assuming bad things one a simple excerpt of code...

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue with Stack Overflow trying to provide good quality answers. Stuff like your answer will then be downvoted, because they are far from "good quality".

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String,String> mymap = new HashMap<>();
// add data to the map
String[] array = mymap.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: you populate an array not an ArrayList with this code.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

```
Arrays.asList(map.keySet().toArray());
```

Would be a good place to start

Comment: Please not that Arrays.asList returns a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` and not a `java.util.ArrayList`